# tx_too_late error on every transaction with a set timeout

Tags: testnet

I just noticed that any transaction with a timeout is failing with tx_too_late error code on the testnet.

If I remove the timeout, then the transaction is submitted with no issue.

I could reproduce on the lab https://laboratory.stellar.org/#?network=test as well.

Has this issue already been reported?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the time on machine is correct.

Here time was with a 2 minutes offset.

Installed `ntp` and checked with `ntpq -p` as [Debian NTP Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NTP) suggests and worked again.